# Why ???? is stored in database even my collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Tags: mysql

When i stored emojis in database it represents question marks sign but when i fetched from database its unicode characters display which is accurate. But my question is why unicode character of emoji are not stored in database instead question marks sign mark are stored.

Comment: It's stored correctly, but rendering as question marks in your command line. Otherwise, you can't retrieve.

Comment: Where and how do you see that the characters are stored as "????". Perhaps whatever application you view the data in doesn't use a font that displays the characters properly.

Comment: I viewed my database in my phpmyadmin.

Comment: It stored as ??? but when i fetch using SELECT  the emoji's unicode characters are displayed in JSON

Comment: @nos I just want to confirm is emjoji's are stored ??? when collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci? because when my collation is utf8_general_ci the emoji's unicode characters stored instead of ???